# Convert a list of char into a single string

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

If I have a list of char like (cons #\C (cons #\O (cons #\M (cons #\P (cons #\U (cons #\T (cons #\E empty))))))), how can I convert it into a string? I'm not allowed to use string-append, substring, implode, and explode. I am also on Beginning Student so I can't use string-join. I've thought about using (string char) but I can't figure out how it'd work recursively.

Or, how would I be able to convert a list of strings into a single string, given the same restrictions above?

Comment: Can you use apply?

Comment: @EricHaney I haven't learned it yet in the course and when I tried it in Beginning Student, it gave errors, so I'm assuming I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [list->string](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list-%7E3estring%29%29) does what you want.

Edit to make the bot happy:

```
(define list-of-chars
   (cons #\C (cons #\O (cons #\M (cons #\P (cons #\U (cons #\T (cons #\E empty))))))))

(list->string list-of-chars)
```

The resulting string is "COMPUTE" as desired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).